# ¿En React Native como hago que se actualice un FlatList si los datos los toma de un array vacío donde voy a agregar objetos?

Tags: react-native

Soy nuevo en React Native y estoy haciendo un punto de venta en donde tengo ciertos productos y al hacer clic en alguno se agregan con un push a un array vacío y se tiene que renderizar del otro lado de la pantalla en un FlatList como se ve en la imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al hacer clic en las imágenes se hace correctamente el push en el array pero el FlaltList no se actualiza o no renderiza los nuevos objetos a menos que yo haga un cambio en el programa para que la pantalla se refresque.

El archivo principal es el App.js y me lo genero en forma de fuction de esta forma:

```
export default function App() {
```

Este es el código principal de App.js donde hago el llamado al FlatList:

```
<View style={styles.productos}>
 <ComprasSet items={ComprasData}></ComprasSet>
</View>
```

Este es ComprasSet donde se hace el FlatList y el ComprasData es el arreglo que empieza en un principio vacío:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ScrollView, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, List, ListItem }from'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Compras from './Compras';
import ComprasData from './ComprasData';


const CardSet = (items) =>(

    <FlatList
        data = {ComprasData}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
        renderItem = { ({item}) => (
            <Compras
            {...item}>
            </Compras>
        )}
    />
)

export default CardSet;
```

Saben alguna forma de actualizar la parte derecha de la pantalla al hacer cambios en la data que ocupa